# Why does gradle try to download a Kotlin compiler during :app:lint?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I was trying to `gradle build` a plain Java Android project. It was an ADT project imported to Android Studio. To my astonishment, at one point Gradle tried to download the Kotlin compiler!

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.2.0)
      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.2.0/kotlin-compiler-26.2.0.jar'.
         > Read timed out
```

1. Why the heck did gradle attempt downloading a big package like the Kotlin compiler
2. How do I prevent that?
3. More generally, how do make gradle ask me before it tries to download anything or at least prevent it from downloading non-dependencies? Such things should be installed by my distro's package manager, after all!

Answer (score 0):

1) Because Gradle supports linting Kotlin code, which requires parsing it, which is implemented using classes in the Kotlin compiler.

2) By not using the lint task I guess?

3) The Kotlin compiler is a dependency. Gradle requires a specific version of this dependency in a specific layout and in a specific location, and it can't use a version installed by your package manager.

Comment: Can't I simply disable Kotlin support for the project?

Answer (score 0):

```
change

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
             }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
              }
  }


 allprojects {
 repositories {
    google()

    jcenter()
       }
      }




to

buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    maven {
url "https://maven2.google.com"
          }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
              }
              }

     allprojects {
          repositories {
                          google()
                          maven {
                                  url "https://maven2.google.com"
                                 }
                          jcenter()
                        }
              }
```